# Сокет чат на go

Tags: golang, websocket, сокет

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь разобраться с сокетами на go.

Как идентифицировать конкретное подключение?

Например, один пользователь даёт серверу такой запрос:

```
{action:message,from_id:111,to_id:222,message:'Привет. Как дела?'}
```

Сервер должен ответить `{status:true}` и перебрать всех подключенных пользователей, найти там пользователя `id 222` и отправить конкретно ему данное сообщение.

Использую пример [отсюда](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysAZ_oqPOo0). С пакетами [отсюда](http://github.com/gorilla/websocket).
Но здесь общий чат. Надо как-то фильтровать, от кого и кому пересылать данные.
Как это делать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Храните подключения клиентов в map-е, где в качестве ключа ID пользователя, что-то вроде такого:

```
var connections = make(map[int]*websocket.Connection, 0)
```

Ну и передавайте сообщения соответственно, как-то так:

```
if connections[userId] != nil {
    connections[userId].Send()
}
```

P.S. Конкретно пакет **github.com/gorilla/websocke**t я не юзал, как там что устроено, не в курсе, я использую **[code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket](http://jan.newmarch.name/go/websockets/chapter-websockets.html)**, так что код исключительно, чтобы обрисовать мысль попонятней. :)

Comment: А можете поподробней написать, хотя бы маленький пример? А то я не очень разобрался ещё.

Comment: Так я же в ответе ссылку дал, там полно примеров http://jan.newmarch.name/go/websockets/chapter-websockets.html

Answer (score 2):

Я в Го небольшой специалист, поэтому могу посоветовать концептуально:

1. Сделать общее хранилище сообщений - 'от','кому','текст','новое/прочитано' - и пусть каждый клиент в него лазит с некой переодичностью и забирает все 'новое'.
2. Рассмотреть вариант с 'именованными каналами' - при подключении нового чат-клиента для него создается именной канал, список каналов хранить в каком-нибудь хэше, где ключ - это ИД клиента. Все сообщения этому клиенту пересылать через соответствующий канал.

Как-то так.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин - С golang не работал, но на С++ когда-то делал такое, надо создать массив и всех подключенных пользователе идентифицировать: id:111 это сокет [0], id:222 это сокет [1] и т.д. В общем, разберись с основными принципами работы сокетов golang - и у тебя все получится!

Comment: Та я впринципи так и думал- а вот только как это сделать?)))